# Как переопределить jquery только на одной странице Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть два AssetBundle. Первый - родительский, используется в общем лэйауте (main.php) для подключения одних и тех же ассетов на всех страницах:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
   public $basePath = '@webroot';
   public $baseUrl = '@web';
   public $css = [
        'css/style.css',
    ];
   public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Второй - дочерний, используется для страницы фотогаллереи, там нужно задействовать свои ассеты, помимо основных, и самое главное поменять jquery на версию ниже. Я подключаю его во вьюшке, в которой выводится содержимое страницы фотогаллереи. Сам bundle:

```
class GalleryAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/gamma/style.css',
        'css/gamma/noJS.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/gamma/modernizr.custom.70736.js',
        'js/gamma/jquery.masonry.min.js',
        'js/gamma/jquery.history.js',
        'js/gamma/js-url.min.js',
        'js/gamma/jquerypp.custom.js',
        'js/gamma/gamma.js',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'app\assets\AppAsset',
    ];
}
```

Как мне переопределить версию jquery в дочернем asset bundle или, что тоже самое, на на одной нужной мне странице (вьюшке) фотогаллереи (только на одной странице)?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я вот так весрию JQuery переопределяю:

```
class Jquery extends JqueryAsset
{
  public $js = [
    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js',
  ];

  public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Customizing Asset Bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles)

Comment: @VasyOk, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Во view можно вызвать:

```
unset($this->assetBundles['yii\web\JqueryAsset']);
```

И там уже как удобнее - либо через другой бандл добавлять нужный jQuery, либо просто через `<script>`-тег.
Способ, конечно, корявый, но вроде бы работает.
Но я бы сменил или допилил бы плагин, который не хочет работать с актуальным jQuery - это более правильный путь.

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя просто по информации из $this-»context определить, что за контроллер и action , а затем с проверкой этого условия в лэйауте зарегистрировать тот или иной бандл?
Кроме того есть некий publishOptions у бандла, я не помню за что он отвечает, посмотрите в документации, возможно это то, что нужно

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо убрать:

```
public $depends = [
    'app\assets\AppAsset',
];
```